# How get base address its shared library?

Tags: python, memory, glibc, elf

i want to get address of testlib.so from libc.so.6 base address.(because of ASLR)

`testlib.so` is shared library.

```
gcc -o ./testlib.so ./testlib.c -fPIC -shared -ldl
```

i makied python code to find memory mapping status.

```
from ctypes import *

#libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
libc = CDLL('/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6')
test = CDLL('./testlib.so')

print libc
print test
```

and result

```
<CDLL '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6', handle 7f17750a09b0 at 7f1774f40210>
<CDLL './testlib.so', handle 15b6ea0 at 7f1774f40550>
```

memory status when running this code.

```
      Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
        0x400000           0x6ea000   0x2ea000        0x0 /usr/bin/python2.7
        0x8e9000           0x8eb000     0x2000   0x2e9000 /usr/bin/python2.7
        0x8eb000           0x962000    0x77000   0x2eb000 /usr/bin/python2.7
        0x962000           0xa6f000   0x10d000        0x0 [heap]
  0x7ffff63e1000     0x7ffff6483000    0xa2000        0x0 /home/wwwlk/Downloads/testlib.so
  ^ target address
  0x7ffff6483000     0x7ffff6682000   0x1ff000    0xa2000 /home/wwwlk/Downloads/testlib.so
  0x7ffff6682000     0x7ffff6683000     0x1000    0xa1000 /home/wwwlk/Downloads/testlib.so
  0x7ffff6683000     0x7ffff6684000     0x1000    0xa2000 /home/wwwlk/Downloads/testlib.so
  ...
  0x7ffff77f0000     0x7ffff79b0000   0x1c0000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
  ^ libc.so.6 address
  0x7ffff79b0000     0x7ffff7bb0000   0x200000   0x1c0000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
  0x7ffff7bb0000     0x7ffff7bb4000     0x4000   0x1c0000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
  0x7ffff7bb4000     0x7ffff7bb6000     0x2000   0x1c4000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
  0x7ffff7bb6000     0x7ffff7bba000     0x4000        0x0 
  ...
  0x7ffff7ff8000     0x7ffff7ffa000     0x2000        0x0 [vvar]
  0x7ffff7ffa000     0x7ffff7ffc000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
  0x7ffff7ffc000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x1000    0x25000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
  0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7ffe000     0x1000    0x26000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
  0x7ffff7ffe000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x1000        0x0 
  0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
  ...
```

i calculated the offset memory, but it was not run. what technic is needed here?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get address of testlib.so from libc.so.6 base address.(because of ASLR)

The base address of `testlib.so` has *nothing* to do with the base address of `libc.so.6`, and the former can not be calculated from the latter.

> i calculated the offset memory, but it was not run.

This statement makes no sense whatsoever.

To get a better answer, try to explain what it is you are actually trying to achieve, what calculations you have performed, what results you expected and what you observed instead.